# Can you tell me the garden plant that is popping up all over my 10x10 garden plot in Wisconsin?

Tags: identification, vegetables, weeds

[image]I have these plants popping up all over my 10x10ft garden in Wisconsin.  I think it may be some kind of flower. I think the leaves look like potato leaves.   I want to know what this is. Is it a weed?

Comment: That is an amaranth. See this recent question: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-and-should-i-rip-it-out

Answer (score 3):

That is an [amaranth, *Amaranthus sp.*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amaranth) This is a very common weed in the temperate U.S..
For control and uses of this plant, refer to this question: [What is this fast growing plant and should I rip it out?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/11176/what-is-this-fast-growing-plant-and-should-i-rip-it-out)

Comment: fwiw, "sp" is what you use when talking, um, generically about a species in a genus, especially if you don't know what the actual species is. I'm with you on calling this _Amaranthus sp_. (maybe _A. retroflexus_?). "sp", btw, is pronounced "spuh" by botanists. Seriously.

Comment: Common name, Pigweed. Edible, seeds can be ground for meal. My sister just bought some decorative versions to plant in the garden. I remarked that it was kind of funny as I spent my childhood weeding its wild cousins out of the garden to feed to the chickens.